# Запуск майнкрафт фордж 1.7.10 через bat

Tags: java

Мне надо запустить майнкрафт фордж 1.7.10 через `bat`

Вот пример [Запуска через лаунчер](https://pastebin.com/raw/iraTKugr)

Но я не знаю как запустить его через `bat`, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вам просто следует найти способ запуска jar файла через bat: [Как запустить jar файл через bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938944/how-to-run-java-application-by-bat-file) `ПУТЬ_ДО_JAVA\bin\java.exe -jar ПУТЬ_ДО_JAR_ФАЙЛА.jar`